# Use Include *pug for subdirectories

Tags: html, pug

I have file head.pug like this

```
head
  h2 
    a(href="") This is title
```

My directory is:

```
contact
  + index.pug
pug
  + head.pug
index.pug
```

In my homepage and contact, I use `index.pug` and I can include head.pug like this

```
include pug/head.pug
and
include ../pug/head.pug
```

and it will print HTML

```
 <head>
     <h2><a href="">This is title</a></h2>
 </head>
```

but in contact directory it should print with link like this

```
 <head>
     <h2><a href="../">This is title</a></h2>
 </head>
```

How can I do ?

Comment: have you tried putting a single quote around the include? include '../pug/head.pug' ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a forward slash `/` in `href`. This should work as far as you are concerned for linking to homepage.

Example:

`head
    h2 
        a(href="/") This is title`

`<head>
    <h2><a href="/">This is title</a></h2>
 </head>`

For non-homepage links, I suggest you keep a global variable for your root and store absolute path of the document you want to link.

Example: `var TITLE_PATH = <project url here >+'public/someFolder/index.html';`

Then, your PUG code becomes

`head
    h2 
        a(href=TITLE_PATH) This is title`